# Proxmox: Add IPs from different subnets to LXC-container

Tags: linux-networking, centos7, lxc, proxmox

I am using proxmox 4.1.

If I add IP-addresses to my `CentOS-7-LXC` I can only do that if this IP is from the same subnet. If I'm using another subnet with another gateway the container is not pingable anymore - I have to remove the IP from the other subnet and reboot the container after that.

The interfaces-configuration of the host node is:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback


auto vmbr0

iface vmbr0 inet static
address 84.xxx.xxx.x4

netmask 255.255.255.240

gateway 84.xxx.xxx.x1

bridge_ports eth0

bridge_stp off

bridge_fd 0
```

A more detailed example:

`84.xxx.xx1.x4` with `gateway 84.xxx.xx1.x1` -> everything is fine

if I add

`84.xxx.xx1.x6` with `gateway 84.xxx.xx1.x1` -> everything is fine

if I add

`84.xxx.xx2.x4` with `gateway 84.xxx.xx2.x1` -> all IPs of the container are not responding to incoming PING. Outgoing PING does not work, too.

The problem is not CentOS-related. A debian-lxc-template has the same problems.